# How to click the last found text in webpage using python selenium

Tags: python, selenium

On Webpage,

There are so many texts with same name

Example

1. Explore
2. Explore
3. Explore
4. Explore
5. Explore

I want to click the 5th or 4th

Note: The count varies every time, when I reload the webpage

1. Explore
2. Explore
3. Explore
4. Explore
5. Explore
6. Explore
7. Explore

I want to click the 6th or 7th text.

Please give solution:

Using the below syntax: not working
driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(), 'Explore')]")

Comment: Please provide us your code.

Comment: What does the HTML of the list look like?

Answer (score 1):

Try select this element by CSS - Selector for example if your 'EXPLORE' element is a paragraph:

```
locator = (By.CSS_SELECTOR,'p *:last-child')

# Alternative 
# locator = (By.CSS_SELECTOR,'p:last-child')

# Alternative
# locator = (By.XPATH,"//p[contains(text(),'Explore')][last()]")

def click_button(self, *locator):
   button = self.driver.find_element(*locator)
   button.click()
```

If you would like click pre-last element :

```
locator = (By.CSS_SELECTOR,'p:nth-last-child(2)')
```

I hope it will be helpfull.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Python slice feature, get the last two Explore, and get the only Explore if there is only one Explore

```
eles = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[contains(., 'Explore')]")

for ele in eles[-2:]:
  ele.click()
```